# Game Center Authenticating Problems

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Im Developing  a new app that uses game center, but unfortunatley im having troubles with game center authentication

here is the authentication code im using:

```
@interface ViewController ()



// A flag indicating whether the Game Center features can be used after a user has been authenticated.
@property (nonatomic) BOOL gameCenterEnabled;

// This property stores the default leaderboard's identifier.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *leaderboardIdentifier;


@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self authenticateLocalPlayer];
    _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
    _leaderboardIdentifier = @"LEADERBOARD ID HERE";
}

- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer {
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else{
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];
            }
            else {
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
                NSLog(@"Game Center Not available");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

i double checked the app id, the leaderboard identifier and i have game center enabled in itunes connect,i also linked gamekit framework,and imported gamekit in View Controller.h, and i have sandbox mode enabled in game center

im using Xcode 5.0.2 on OS X Mavericks

Could Someone please Help? Its Making me CRAZYY!!

Regards :)

Comment: why do you print the authentication error inside "if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated)". Make it an else if condition at the same level as [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated and see the error description

Answer (score 0):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in github
**Easy Game Center Swift**

[https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift](https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Game-Center-Swift.git)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this issue, you need to enable the Game Center capability.

[image]